# Cannot access the correct this context inside the axios callback react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

I'm able to access the correct `this` context inside the `signInWithEmail` function, however the `this` context inside the callback function from axios is `undefined`. I'm able to call the user action `SignInUser` inside the component's render with: `this.props.signInUser`. But I want to call it based on the api response.

Here's the code from my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { signInUser } from "../actions/UserActions"
import API from "../api/config";

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props)
        this.state = { username: '', password: '' };
        this.signInWithEmail = this.signInWithEmail.bind(this);
    }

    signInWithEmail(username, pass) {
        console.log(this.props); // correct context here
        API.post('/token/', {
            username: username,
            password: pass
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(this.props); // undefined here
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // Show error or redirect
            console.log(error);
        });
}

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>access: {this.props.userState.accessToken}</Text>
                <Text>refres: {this.props.userState.isSignout.toString()}</Text>
                <Text>username: {this.state.username}</Text>
                <Text>password: {this.state.password}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> Username </Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
                    value={this.state.username}
                />
                <Text style={styles.inputLabel}> Password </Text>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    secureTextEntry
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                    value={this.state.password}
                />
                <Button title="Sign in with email" onPress={() => this.signInWithEmail(this.state.username, this.state.password)} />
                {/* <Button title="Sign in with email" onPress={() => this.props.signInUser("dummy-token", "dummy-refresh")} /> */}
            </View>
        );
    }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    label: {
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: 'normal',
        marginBottom: 48,
        borderColor: "#FFF222"
    },
    divider: {
        borderBottomColor: '#000000',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginVertical: 10,
    },
    input: {
        backgroundColor: '#F0EEEE',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginBottom: 10,
        fontSize: 18
    },
    inputLabel: {
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { userState } = state
    return { userState }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    bindActionCreators({
        signInUser,
    }, dispatch)
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Comment: The easiest fix would be to make the function where you're getting `undefined` into an arrow function, which autobinds to the context where it's defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arrow function (`=>`) inside the `then` callback. Inside the arrow function, the `Context` (this) will not be changed automatically. Try this:

```js
API.post('/token/', {
        username: username,
        password: pass
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(this.props);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

**N.B.** Inside the Simple function (you are using as a .then() callback) `Context` (this) would be global/window!

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function to preserve context of react component

```
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(this.props); // undefined here
})....
```